# how to customize Notika Bar charts in mvc core

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I m looking up for a way to customize Notika Web Templete bar charts.

I see only this snipped for charts :

```
<div class="sale-statistic-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                <div class="sale-statistic-inner notika-shadow mg-tb-30">
                    <div class="curved-inner-pro" dir="rtl">
                        <div class="curved-ctn">
                            <h2 class="titr"></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bar-chart" class="flot-chart bar-three bar-hm-three"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and  im very basic in jquery and cant customize it for our project (mvc core )
is there any new tools for dot net core web applications?

[image]

Comment: notika is a free admin dashbord and you can access it via https://github.com/puikinsh/notika

Comment: I want to customize a main chart in a index-3.html page

Comment: thank you .  It has a dynamic-chart only . but I want only column chart with two columns for any stuffs and I want to change the tooltip and values.  so how can i change them